# Ассоциация :has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеем две модели `Tag` и `Video`. Связь между ними:

```
#video.rb
class Video
  belongs_to :tag
end

#tag.rb
class Tag
  has_many :videos
end
```

Все видео одного тега получаем легко: `tag.videos`

Но есть задача получать видео от нескольких выбранных тегов. Например `Tag.where(условие).videos` - понятно что это не работает. Как выполнить задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такое комбо: `joins` и `merge`.

`joins` соединяет вместе (в одном множестве строк) ассоциации, позволяя накладывать через `where` условия не только на поля исходной таблицы, но и на таблицы со связанными объектами.

Сначала вам понадобится запрос на теги. Если у вас есть только набор их `id`, то это такой запрос:

```
Tag.where(id: [1, 2, 3])
```

Если это "чьи-то теги", то может быть и такое:

```
@user.tags
```

Но это выборка тегов. Надо её применить к видео, "присоединив" (`joins`) к каждому его тег. Тут в дело вступает `merge`:

```
Video.joins(:tag).merge(
  @user.tags
  # А можно и так:
  # Tag.where(name: %w(раз два))
)
```

На самом деле, это можно сделать и без `merge`, просто указав в `where` хэш условий для указанной таблицы, такого толка:

```
Video.joins(:tag).where(tags:
  { id: [1, 2, 3] }
)
```

...и иногда выбора нет — если мы имеем дело с алиасом, например. Но это дебри.

Обычно `merge` даёт более понятный и DRY код, за счёт возможности применять скоупы и ассоциации от других моделей. Хотя в случае с `merge` ассоциаций (вроде `@user.tags`) иногда стоит проверять, что запрос действительно делает то, что задумано (пишите тесты!).

Answer (score 1):

Надо использовать has_many :through связь, через класс Taggable (tag_id: integer, video_id: integer)

```
#video.rb
class Video
  has_many :taggables
  has_many :tags, through: :taggable
end

#taggable.rb
class Taggable
  belongs_to :tags
  belongs_to :videos
end 

#tag.rb
class Tag
  has_many :taggables
  has_many :videos, through: :taggable
end
```

Выборку делаем так:

```
Video.joins(:taggables).where('taggables.tag_id IN (?)', array_of_tags_ids)
```

Comment: спасибо, но не хотелось бы менять связь )

Comment: Я вам предложил стандартную организацию для тэгов и объектов. Ваша текущая организация связей позволяет работать только с одним тэгом на объект. Это довольно распространенный подход для организации категорий; тэги же подразумевают множественное назначение на один объект.

Comment: да, вы правы. буду переделывать. а использвать has_and_belongs_to_many связь тут уместно?